# Berliner Weisse questions

Tags: fermentation, bottle-conditioning, sour, berliner-weisse

I have a Berliner Weisse (1.035 O.G.) that has been fermenting on WLP630 (berliner weisse lacto blend) for about 5 days now. This is my first attempt at both a sour style beer and a starting gravity this low. My main question is about fermentation and conditioning, should I ferment like I normally would then transfer off the yeast and continue sour in a "secondary" and if so is there any suggestions on proper timing for original fermentation and then conditioning? Also I am considering going straight to bottle with this batch, I have bottled a couple batches a long time ago and am curios if I should do anything different bottling a sour especially one with this high of carb. My last question is about fermentation temp, I was up around 74F for a couple days before i could get it down just below 70F, should I expect any off flavor or will the sour aspect cover it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The yeast may have out paced the lacto at 74F and fermented much of your fermentables.  This may leave less for the lacto to work on and it may not sour as much as you were hoping.

I'd leave the whole thing in primary for 3 weeks, then sample it.  If its still not soured move it from the cake to a fresh fermentor just to get off the cake as a precaution against autolysis.

Comment: so it's been about 15 days now on the yeast, my gravity is right at 1.010 and it taste like a watery wheat beer but I am looking for that sour characteristic to shine through. I will be racking off the yeast here in the next couple days ( like brewchez suggested) so is there anything I can add during transfer for the lacto to munch on?